# Insert function declaration in llvm with two arguments of type "Value*" and "string"

Tags: llvm

I need to insert the declaration of the function `foo(Value*, std::string)` using an llvm module pass. How do I pass the function arguments type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot because llvm **Value.h** is internal library.
Finally I realised that the `Value*` was actually an `IcmpInst*` which can be cast to char(1 byte boolean value) in C.
Finally the function which I needed to insert was `foo(char,char*)` in a C file using llvm pass which was trivial.

Comment: I know I am late to the party, but could you please add some code as to how you called foo with two parameters. I currently am trying to do that with no luck.

Comment: I think I figured it out actually. How I did that was I created a vector which contained pointers to LLVM's value objects using ```std::vector< llvm::Value* > putsArgs```. I then converted all my arguments to type llvm::Value and pushed them into the vector. You can then convert the vector into an ArrayRef using: ```llvm::ArrayRef< llvm::Value* > argsRef(putsArgs)```. Finally you pass argsRef to your createCall function ```builder.CreateCall(foo, argsRef);```